# Remove all adjacent duplicates in a string using a Stack

Tags: c++, strings, stack

> Input: careermonk
>      Output:    camonk
>
> Input: mississippi
>      Output:    m

I want to improve this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define max 1000

class Stack
{
  int top;
public:
  char stk[max];
  Stack()
  {
    top = -1;
  }
  bool isStackEmpty();
  void push(char);
  char pop();
  std::string modifyString(std::string);
private:
  void removeAdjacentDuplicate(std::string);
};

bool Stack::isStackEmpty()
{
   if (top == -1)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}

void Stack::push(char val)
{
   int s = max - 1;
   if (top < s)
   {
     top = top + 1;
     stk[top] = val;
   }
   else
    std::cerr << "Stack Overflow \n";
}

char Stack::pop()
{
   if (isStackEmpty() == true)
       std::cerr << "Stack Underflow \n";
   else
   {
      --top;
      return stk[top + 1];
   }
}

void Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate(std::string str)
{
   int len = str.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      if (isStackEmpty() == true)
      {
         push(str[i]);
      }
      else if (str[i] == stk[top])
      {
         int discard = pop();
      }
      else
      {
         push(str[i]);
      }
   }
}

std::string Stack::modifyString(std::string str)
{
   removeAdjacentDuplicate(str);
   str.resize(top + 1);
   for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
   {
     str[i] = stk[i];
   }
   str[top + 1] = '\0';
   return str;
}

int main()
{
   Stack stack1;
   std::string str = "careermonk";
   std::cout << "Orignal string : " << str << "\n";
   str = stack1.modifyString(str);
   std::cout << "New string     : " << str << "\n";

   Stack stack2;
   std::string str2 = "mississippi";
   std::cout << "Original string : " << str2 << "\n";
   str2 = stack2.modifyString(str2);
   std::cout << "New string      : " << str2 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: a Stack is FILO, so maybe try and reverse the order of:  void Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate(std::string str) and see if this helps.

Comment: How do you want to improve it?

Comment: @Juho using STL or better logic.

Comment: What do you want to happen with odd numbers of similar characters, such as `steeel`?  Your code appears to only remove adjacent pairs, but the example inputs don't give a clear requirement.

Comment: Better real-life examples: `gazetteer`, `addressees`, `keenness`

Answer (score 2):

### std::array

You could use std::array and get rid of `max` define. In general, I'd like to suggest avoiding defines which can conflict with any stl names by any cost.

One of Windows header has its own `#define max` and this is horrible when your code wants `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, `std::max({a, b, c})`, etc.

Things are even worse if you're writing header only library:

```
#if defined max
#  undef max
#  define HAD_MAX
#endif 

// ... C++ code ...

#if defined HAD_MAX
#  define max(a, b) ... // copy-paste from Windows.h
#endif
```

### Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate signature

Signature of `Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate(std::string)` can be improved:

At least, it doesn't actually removes anything. It perform some kind of initialization from given string, so consider choosing more intuitive name.

Additionally, avoid copying parameter - you can use `const std::string&`

### Stack::modifyString

`Stack::modifyString` also says nothing about its purpose and it also constructs another string instead of modifying something. Consider better naming.

### Use standard library

When copying N characters, consider using standard library functions instead of `for` loop: `strncpy, memcpy, std::copy_n` and others works fine, looks clear and may perform some performance optimizations.

### Use standard library (alternative)

As alternative, you can construct new string directly from `Stack::stk`. There is corresponding constructor: `std::string(const char* s, size_t n);`. In this case you can pass all std::string parameters by const reference.

BTW, I'm assure you're already bored with my variable naming suggestions, so I don't need to add another one here :)

### Non-const public members are dangerous

### Consider using some naming conventions

It's hard to determine whether some variable is a class member or not. In order to simplify your work, make member variables somehow. You can use m_member, member_, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid arbitrary limits

The definition of `max` (and especially as a `#define` rather than as a C++ constant) is worrying.  Especially as the checking simply prints a diagnostic and then ignores the action that was requested.

## Simple refactorings

`if (test) return true; else return false;` is the same as `return test;`.  So we can write

```
bool Stack::isStackEmpty()
{
   return top == -1;
}
```

Similarly, testing `==true` is redundant:

```
   if (isStackEmpty())
```

## A more involved refactoring

```
void Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate(std::string str)
{
   int len = str.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      if (isStackEmpty() == true)
      {
         push(str[i]);
      }
      else if (str[i] == stk[top])
      {
         int discard = pop();
      }
      else
      {
         push(str[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Here, we're iterating over the elements of `str`, so we can use `for (char c: str)`, which is clearer and less error-prone than using indexes.

The first and last branch are the same, so we can change the condition to bring them together:

```
void Stack::removeAdjacentDuplicate(const std::string& str)
{
   for (auto c: str) {
      if (isStackEmpty() || c != stk[top]) {
         push(c);
      } else {
         (void)pop();
      }
   }
}
```

## Think like standard algorithms

We have standard algorithms - one similar to our needs is `std::unique()`.  This makes a single pass over its input, and returns an iterator to the new end position.

If we make a function with a similar interface, we can use the 'erase/remove' idiom to replace characters in a string:

```
#include <string>

std::string repeatedly_remove_duplicates(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(repeatedly_remove_duplicates(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
    return s;
}
```

How do we implement `repeatedly_remove_duplicates()`?  I would assume a single pass called `remove_duplicates()`, and call it until the returned end doesn't change:

```
template <typename Iter>
Iter repeatedly_remove_duplicates(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    Iter new_end;
    while ((new_end = remove_duplicates(begin, end)) != end) {
        end = new_end;
    }
    return end;
}
```

(I've made this a template, so it can work with any container.  The also allows us to make `repeatedly_remove_duplicates()` a template to work with any string type, including `std::wstring`, for instance).

Now, we need an implementation of `remove_duplicates`.  We can do this in-place:

```
template <typename Iter>
Iter remove_duplicates(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    auto dest = begin;
    if (begin == end) { return dest; }

    auto prev = begin;
    bool is_duplicate = false;
    while (++begin != end) {
        if (*begin == *prev) {
            is_duplicate = true;
        } else {
            if (!is_duplicate) {
                *dest++ = *prev;
            }
            is_duplicate = false;
            prev = begin;
        }
    }

    if (!is_duplicate) {
        *dest++ = *prev;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

There are other ways to do this; we might use `std::adjacent_find()`, for example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename Iter>
Iter remove_duplicates(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    using not_equal_to = std::not_equal_to<typename Iter::value_type>;

    auto dest = begin;

    do {
        Iter pair = std::adjacent_find(begin, end);
        if (dest != begin) {
            std::copy(begin, pair, dest);
            dest += std::distance(begin, pair);
        } else {
            dest = pair;
        }
    } while (begin != end);

    return dest;
}
```

---

## Putting it all together

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename Iter>
Iter remove_duplicates(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    using not_equal_to = std::not_equal_to<typename Iter::value_type>;

    auto dest = begin;

    do {
        Iter pair = std::adjacent_find(begin, end);
        if (dest != begin) {
            std::copy(begin, pair, dest);
            dest += std::distance(begin, pair);
        } else {
            dest = pair;
        }
#ifdef REMOVE_PAIR_ONLY
        begin = pair;
        if (pair != end) {
            begin += 2;
        }
#else
        begin = std::adjacent_find(pair, end, not_equal_to());
        if (begin != end) {
            ++begin;
        }
#endif
    } while (begin != end);

    return dest;
}

template <typename Iter>
Iter repeatedly_remove_duplicates(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    Iter new_end;
    while ((new_end = remove_duplicates(begin, end)) != end) {
        end = new_end;
    }
    return end;
}


#include <string>
std::string repeatedly_remove_duplicates(std::string s)
{
    s.erase(repeatedly_remove_duplicates(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
    return s;
}

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (auto i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << " ⇒ "
                  << repeatedly_remove_duplicates(argv[i])
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```